# How to : Azure Web App using On Premise Windows Authenticated SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I want to use On Premise Windows Authenticated SQL with Azure Web App. I am new to Azure. what are all possible ways to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: "All the possible ways"...? This question is too broad. What problem are you stuck on? Not, "how can I do this large task?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use On Premise Windows Authenticated SQL with Azure Web App.

**Unfortunately**, it is not supported by Azure WebApp. If we want to use the  Windows Authenticated, we need to ensure that Windows Authentication is enabled for the web server. We could [remote to Azure website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) to check that there is no Windows Authenticated under the Authentication option, details please refer to the screenshot.

[image].

If you stick on absolutely use On Premise Windows Authenticated and host your website on Azure, you could use Azure Windows VM to host your website. And need to join the VM to your AD, that meanings both VMs are in the same network.

As you use on-premise machine, you will need to create a [site to site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal).